# Adding sql driver to JasperReports Server Pro

Tags: jasperserver

I want to use ms sql server driver in *JasperReports Server Pro*. The driver is not installed and in the tutorial there is a **select driver** button at the right side of **JDBC:Driver**. But in my server (6.2 pro) there is no such a button to add the driver. How can I install the new drivers?

Screen shut of my server is as you see at the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that you have the correct library at hand. MS SQL driver can be obtained [from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt484311.aspx).

Afterwards do this:

> Now you need to copy the driver (the .jar file) to the classpath of your application server to enable JasperServer to find it.
>
> In general it's best to copy the driver to the application server's shared library location. Refer to your application server documentation for exact locations.
>
> Sample locations:
>
> **Tomcat5**: \common\lib
>   (for example in a JapserServer Bundle install on windows this is located at:  C:/Program Files (x86)/jasperreports-server-4.0/apache-tomcat/lib )
>
> **Tomcat6**: \lib
>   (for example: /var/lib/tomcat6/lib)
>
> **JBoss5**: \server\all\lib

Now restart your server. Depending on the operation system you use this can be done several ways. The driver should now be available.

[Source](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/connecting-jasperreports-server-your-database)